# OpenComponents returns TEMPLATE_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERROR for custom compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, micro-frontend, open-components

I'm trying to setup [OpenComponents](https://github.com/opencomponents/oc) with custom compiler (based on [oc-template-react](https://github.com/opencomponents/oc-template-react)).

My component's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hi-there",
  "description": "Hello World OC",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "oc": {
    "files": {
      "data": "server.js",
      "template": {
        "src": "app.js",
        "type": "oc-my-template"
      }
    },
    "parameters": {
      "name": {
        "default": "World",
        "description": "Your name",
        "example": "Jane Doe",
        "mandatory": false,
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "oc-my-template-compiler": "*"
  }
}
```

`oc-my-template-compiler` is installed. Packaging works fine, but I'm getting following error from registry:

> GET http://localhost:3030/hi-there/1.0.0/?__oc_Retry=0

```
{
  code: "TEMPLATE_NOT_SUPPORTED"
  error: "oc-my-template is not a supported oc-template"
  name: "hi-there"
  requestVersion: "1.0.0"
}
```

I think I should register template with [oc.registerTemplate](https://github.com/opencomponents/oc/wiki/The-template-system#client-side-rendering) but I'm not sure where should I do it. Should not dev registry take care about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look into the "oc-client" component (visiting http://localhost:3030/oc-client) you should have a snippet of what is required to correctly render your component with the custom template.

One common thing to do if you are using OC in a dynamic web app, is to server-side render the oc-client component in order to serve the html page with the oc-client already initialised with all the supported templates.